# PHP SDK Facebook get message to all friends

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, facebook

Hello I have some code but I want to add something to it, I want to post something to ALL my friends walls to give them all a message how can I do this? So I want to log in with my account and post to all my friends just with 1 click, is there a way to do this or any other way to get my friends attentions to my message? here is my current code.

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '**********' , '**********' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://centralrp.co.uk/ashisawesome/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Login with Facebook</title>
<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?>      <!--  After user login  -->
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
  <h1>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME']; ?></h1>
  <p>Welcome to "facebook login" tutorial</p>
  </div>
<div class="span4">
 <ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">Image</li>
    <li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture"></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook ID</li>
<li><?php echo  $_SESSION['FBID']; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook fullname</li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook Email</li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['EMAIL']; ?></li>
<div><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
</ul></div></div>
    <?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login --> 
<div class="container">
<h1>Login with Facebook</h1>
           Not Connected
<div>
      <a href="fbconfig.php">Login with Facebook</a></div>
     <div> <a href="http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/"  title="Login with facebook">View Post</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That´s not possible at all for obvious reasons: It would be pure spam.

You can only post to your own wall with the API, and you have to go through a preview process with the require permission, so Facebook can check if you don´t spam. You should consider reading the platform policy before creating any App.